# $\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+a^2+b^2)^{\frac12}}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I am trying to solve below integration

> $$\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+a^2+b^2)^{\frac12}}$$

I tried substituting $x=a \tan u$. Then I ended up with $$\int\frac{du}{(a)(b^2+a^2\sec^2u)^{\frac12}}.$$ I am not able to continue after this. Appreciate a small help on this.

Comment: Have you tried $x = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\tan u$? That at least gets rid of the square root.

Comment: @rogerl thanks. I tried it. In that case I am not able to isolate the term $(x^2+b^2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using rogerl's suggestion, letting $x=c\tan\theta$ where $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ gives

$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)\sqrt{x^2+a^2+b^2}}dx=\int\frac{1}{(c^2\tan^2\theta+a^2)(c\sec\theta)}\cdot c\sec^2\theta d\theta$

$\displaystyle=\int\frac{\sec\theta}{a^2\sec^2\theta+b^2\tan^2\theta} d\theta$ $\;$[since $c^2\tan^2\theta+a^2=(a^2+b^2)\tan^2\theta+a^2=a^2\sec^2\theta+b^2\tan^2\theta$]

$=\displaystyle\int\frac{\cos\theta}{a^2+b^2\sin^2\theta} d\theta=\frac{1}{b}\int\frac{1}{a^2+u^2} du$  $\;\;\;$ (letting $u=b\sin\theta$)

$\displaystyle=\frac{1}{ab}\tan^{-1}\frac{u}{a}+C=\frac{1}{ab}\tan^{-1}\frac{b\sin\theta}{a}+C=\frac{1}{ab}\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{bx}{a\sqrt{x^2+a^2+b^2}}\bigg)+C$

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask for small help, here is a hint, that I normally wouldn't consider being an answer:

Try
$$
u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+x^2}}.
$$
If you can take it from here, fine. Otherwise, ask for more steps...

**Update with further details:**

You will get (at least, I got)
$$
x^2=\frac{(a^2+b^2)u^2}{1-u^2},\quad\text{and}\quad du=\frac{a^2+b^2}{(a^2+b^2+x^2)^{3/2}}\,dx
$$
Now insert this and simplify as much as you can. You will get something really simple.

Comment: Thnks heaps. should it be $$
tan(u)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+x^2}}.
$$? can u give lil more steps.Thanks again

Comment: No, I meant the substitution I wrote. More details are now added. Please try to do the calculation carefully.

Comment: (Do you want $1-u^2$ in the denominator instead of $u^2-1$?)

Comment: @user84413 Thanks! I first had a minus sign in front, and forgot to change the denominator when removing it.

Answer (score 0):

With $\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} $

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)\sqrt{x^2+a^2+b^2}}
=\int \frac{dt}{a^2+b^2t^2}=\frac1{ab}\tan^{-1}\frac{bt}a+C
$$